# How to query AWS Cloudwatch metrics with JSONs?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to define the cloudwatch metrics I want to query in JSON format so that I can just feed the JSON files to cloudwatch to read those metrics, instead of composing `Metric`, `MetricStat`, `MetricDataQuery` objects during compile time (as shown in this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javav2-cloudwatch-src-main-java-com-example-cloudwatch-GetMetricData.java.html)). In this way, I can dynamically add new queries during runtime. I know this is achievable with AWS CLI (that `metric-data-queries.json` file in this [example](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-getmetricdata-api/)). But I wonder if the Cloudwatch SDK has any API that can do this as well? Alternatively, I can send an HTTP request to Cloudwatch server with the JSON file as the payload ([example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricData.html)). However, generating the `Authorization` header ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/making-api-requests.html)) is too complex. Any better recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

- by looking at https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudwatch/model/GetMetricDataRequest.html, I don't think there's an easy way to convert a JSON to GetMetricDataRequest.
- AWS CLI is implemented in Python, but it essentially calls AWS SDK in the similar way your code uses AWS SDK. I guess the reason AWS CLI supports JSON argument input is that whoever developed that AWS CLI command added extra code logic to parse the JSON argument, iterate the content, and form the GetMetricDataRequest.
- You can use the same approach to build a helper function in your code to convert a JSON object to GetMetricDataRequest.
- As you realised, directly calling AWS HTTP API has a lot of overheads, such as rate-limit handling, re-try attempts, authentication, etc. I wouldn't recommend going down that path.